# pandas: fill a column with some numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I am using python2.7 and pandas 0.11.0.

I try to fill a column of a dataframe using DataFrame.apply(func). The func() function is supposed to return a numpy array (1x3).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
print(df)

              A         B         C
    0  0.910142  0.788300  0.114164
    1 -0.603282 -0.625895  2.843130
    2  1.823752 -0.091736 -0.107781
    3  0.447743 -0.163605  0.514052
```

The function used for testing purpose:

```
def test(row):
   # some complex calc here 
   # based on the values from different columns 
   return np.array((1,2,3))

df['D'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)

[...]
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, indices imply 3
```

The funny is that when I create the dataframe from scratch, it works pretty well, and returns as expected:

```
dic = {'A': {0: 0.9, 1: -0.6, 2: 1.8, 3: 0.4}, 
     'C': {0: 0.1, 1: 2.8, 2: -0.1, 3: 0.5}, 
     'B': {0: 0.7, 1: -0.6, 2: -0.1, 3: -0.1},
     'D': {0:np.array((1,2,3)), 
          1:np.array((1,2,3)), 
          2:np.array((1,2,3)), 
          3:np.array((1,2,3))}}

df= pd.DataFrame(dic)
print(df)
         A    B    C          D
    0  0.9  0.7  0.1  [1, 2, 3]
    1 -0.6 -0.6  2.8  [1, 2, 3]
    2  1.8 -0.1 -0.1  [1, 2, 3]
    3  0.4 -0.1  0.5  [1, 2, 3]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should avoid using `list`s/`tuple`s in `DataFrame`s or `Series`. Why not just have 3 columns in `df` or a separate `DataFrame` with your columns?

Comment: I guess sometimes vector form is more natural for some quantity, e.g., coordinates. `df.endPoint-df.startPoint` is obviously more preferable to `np.c_[df.endX-df.startX, df.endY-df.startY, df.endZ-df.startZ]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you try to return multiple values from the function that is passed to `apply`, and the DataFrame you call the `apply` on has the same number of item along the axis (in this case columns) as the number of values you returned, Pandas will create a DataFrame from the return values with the same labels as the original DataFrame. You can see this if you just do:

```
>>> def test(row):
        return [1, 2, 3]
>>> df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> df.apply(test, axis=1)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
3  1  2  3
```

And that is why you get the error, since you cannot assign a DataFrame to DataFrame column.

If you return any other number of values, it will return just a series object, that can be assigned:

```
>>> def test(row):
       return [1, 2]
>>> df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> df.apply(test, axis=1)
0    [1, 2]
1    [1, 2]
2    [1, 2]
3    [1, 2]
>>> df['D'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)
>>> df
          A         B         C       D
0  0.333535  0.209745 -0.972413  [1, 2]
1  0.469590  0.107491 -1.248670  [1, 2]
2  0.234444  0.093290 -0.853348  [1, 2]
3  1.021356  0.092704 -0.406727  [1, 2]
```

I'm not sure why Pandas does this, and why it does it only when the return value is a `list` or an `ndarray`, since it won't do it if you return a `tuple`:

```
>>> def test(row):
        return (1, 2, 3)
>>> df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
>>> df['D'] = df.apply(test, axis=1)
>>> df
          A         B         C          D
0  0.121136  0.541198 -0.281972  (1, 2, 3)
1  0.569091  0.944344  0.861057  (1, 2, 3)
2 -1.742484 -0.077317  0.181656  (1, 2, 3)
3 -1.541244  0.174428  0.660123  (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Hi Viktor! thanks to answer. So if I understand you correctly ,there is no way to pass a numpy array?

Comment: @Nic If the length of the numpy array is not the same as the number of columns your code will work, but it's not intended to be used in such a way. As Phillip Cloud said you should avoid placing lists or arrays in your Series. You should create multiple Series (that is, multiple columns in your DataFrame).

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll then follow your advice, and go for 3 columns.
@Phillip: sorry I missed your comment at first reading.

Comment: I wish to keep some array in the same dataframe, I wish there was a supported way to do this.

Comment: Is there any alternative to pandas that would work ? I don't understand the point of not letting users choosing what object they want to put inside a dataframe.

Comment: @agemO supposedly you can still get numpy arrays by doing `df.apply(tuple_test, axis=1).apply(np.array)`, but I cannot get this to work for me yet. [See this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45548426/3670871).

Comment: An efficient and dirty solution is indeed to make a decorator that put any function output into a tuple, then turn back the tuple into the original output when operations (apply, agg) are done. This is what I do now on a regular basis