# Adding arrays to dataframe column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume I have this dataframe `df`:

```
   'Location'  'Rec ID'  'Duration'
0     Houston       126          17
1     Chicago       338        19.3
```

I would like to add a column with arrays corresponding to my recordings like:

```
   'Location'  'Rec ID'  'Duration'                           'Rec'
0     Houston       126          17    [0.2, 0.34, 0.45, ..., 0.28]
1     Chicago       338        19.3    [0.12, 0.3, 0.41, ..., 0.39]
```

When I do the `df.set_value()` command I get the following error:

***ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.***

Comment: Take alook http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646076/add-numpy-array-as-column-to-pandas-data-frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest is to assign `list` of `lists`, only you need same length of `lists` as `length` of `DataFrame`:

```
arr = [[0.2, 0.34, 0.45, 0.28], [0.12, 0.3, 0.41, 0.39]]
print (arr)
[[0.2, 0.34, 0.45, 0.28], [0.12, 0.3, 0.41, 0.39]]

print (len(arr))
2
print (len(df))
2

df["'Rec'"] = arr
print (df)
   'Location'     'Rec  ID'  'Duration'                    'Rec'
0           0  Houston  126        17.0  [0.2, 0.34, 0.45, 0.28]
1           1  Chicago  338        19.3  [0.12, 0.3, 0.41, 0.39]
```

---

If use `numpy array`, first convert [`tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
arr = np.array([[0.2, 0.34, 0.45, 0.28], [0.12, 0.3, 0.41, 0.39]])
print (arr)
[[ 0.2   0.34  0.45  0.28]
 [ 0.12  0.3   0.41  0.39]]

df["'Rec'"] = arr.tolist()

print (df)
   'Location'     'Rec  ID'  'Duration'                    'Rec'
0           0  Houston  126        17.0  [0.2, 0.34, 0.45, 0.28]
1           1  Chicago  338        19.3  [0.12, 0.3, 0.41, 0.39]
```

Comment: @piRSquared - Thank you. I dont test it.