# Replace a column in a data frame with a numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas data frame with shape 1725 rows X 4 columns.

```
      date     size           state type   
408      1    32000        Virginia  EDU
...
```

I need to replace the `state` column with the following numpy array with shape (1725, 52).

```
[[0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
...
[0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The final result should be like this:

```
      date     size                   state type   
408      1    32000 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]  EDU
...
```

So far I tried the following based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646076/add-numpy-array-as-column-to-pandas-data-frame):

```
col = 2
df.iloc[:, col] = np_arr.tolist()
```

The problem is that I get this error:

```
    dataSet.iloc[:, col] = tempData.tolist()
  File "/home/marcus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 205, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/home/marcus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 527, in _setitem_with_indexer
    "Must have equal len keys and value "
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray
```

Comment: `df['states'] = tempData.tolist()` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to try reshaping your array to a turn it into a single feature before actually adding it to the column. This problem often arises when preprocessing. Try with the following:

```
df['state'] = np_arr.reshape(-1,1)
```

If that doesn't work, you can try first turning it into an array and then to a list:

```
df['state'] = np_arr.toarray().tolist()
```

Working with multiple columns:
You can try doing these replacements in a `for` loop using either `list(df)`  which returns a list of all the column names and then accessing them with their index value or with `iloc[]`:

```
cols = list(df) #Get a list with all column names
column_positions = [0,2,4,5] #Here we will select columns in position 0,2,4 and 5
for i in column_positions: 
    df[cols[i]] = np_arr.tolist() #Iterate over those specific columns and replace their values.
```

Comment: The second option worked. Thank you. Although np_arr is already in numpy array format so toarray() is not necessary. Do you know how to make this method more generic? For example using the column number instead of its name.

Comment: You can either use `.iloc[]` as you stated in your example, or `list(df)` that will return a list with all column names, then you pass the index value of the column you wish to access and that will work too.

Comment: I couldn't get the `iloc[]` method to work but the `list(df)` solved my problem. Thank you!