# Store numpy.array in cells of a Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which I would like to store 'raw' `numpy.array`:

```
df['COL_ARRAY'] = df.apply(lambda r: np.array(do_something_with_r), axis=1)
```

but it seems that `pandas` tries to 'unpack' the numpy.array.

Is there a workaround? Other than using a wrapper (see edit below)?

I tried `reduce=False` with no success.

**EDIT**

This works, but I have to use the 'dummy' `Data` class to wrap around the array, which is unsatisfactory and not very elegant.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

meas = pd.read_excel(DATA_FILE)
meas['DATA'] = meas.apply(
    lambda r: Data(np.array(pd.read_csv(r['filename'])))),
    axis=1
)
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use a wrapper around the numpy array i.e. pass the numpy array as list

```
a = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [a]})
```

Output:

```
             a
0  [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Or you can use `apply(np.array)` by creating the tuples i.e. if you have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'a': ['on', 'on', 'off', 'off'],
                   'b': ['on', 'off', 'on', 'off']})

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda r: tuple(r), axis=1).apply(np.array)
```

Output :

```
     a    b  id            new
0   on   on   1    [on, on, 1]
1   on  off   2   [on, off, 2]
2  off   on   3   [off, on, 3]
3  off  off   4  [off, off, 4]
```

```
df['new'][0]
```

Output :

```
array(['on', 'on', '1'], dtype='<U2')
```

Comment: That works, but then I'd rather use a dummy class instead of a list.

Comment: Does that work if instead of `tuple(r)` you do something like `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`, ie. a 2-dim array?

Comment: `tuple(r)` works with 2D array too. Did you mean replacing tuple(r) with 2D np.array?

Comment: Yes. I mean, I understand your solution, and it works, but what if I want to have a 2D np.array in the `new` column (and not a 1D array as shown)?

Comment: Can you add the expected output in your question? All the elements in the row should be of numpy array if you want to create a new 2D array. My solution works in that case. If its mixed type you have to use if else first to make it a numpy array.

Answer (score 32):

If you first set a column to have type `object`, you can insert an array without any wrapping:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1])
df[1] = df[1].astype(object)
df.loc[1, 1] = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
df
```

Output:

```
    1
1   [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can wrap the Data Frame data args in square brackets to maintain the `np.array` in each cell:

```
one_d_array = np.array([1,2,3])
two_d_array = one_d_array*one_d_array[:,np.newaxis]
two_d_array

array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])


pd.DataFrame([
    [one_d_array],
    [two_d_array] ])

                                   0
0                          [1, 2, 3]
1  [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]]
```

Comment: Those become `list`s no?

Comment: @javadba I set the above output to `df` and see `print(type(df.iloc[0,0]))` -->
_<class 'numpy.ndarray'>_  This is Pandas 0.23.0.  Are you seeing something different with another version?

Comment: You are correct actually - one of the more highly upvoted answers made it sound like the ndarray would be converted to a list.  I just tested this. `without` the brackets we get `rows` in the `df` and `with` brackets we get  `ndarray`s as you say

Answer (score 2):

Preset the type of your column to `object`, this will allow you to store a NumPy array as-is:

```
df['COL_ARRAY'] = pd.Series(dtype='object')

df['COL_ARRAY'] = df.apply(lambda r: np.array(do_something_with_r), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a DataFrame *`ds`* and it has a column named as 'class'. If *`ds`*['class'] contains strings or numbers, and you want to change them with `numpy.ndarray`s or `list`s, the following code would help. In the code, *`class2vector`* is a `numpy.ndarray` or `list` and *`ds_class`* is a filter condition.

`ds['class'] = ds['class'].map(lambda x: class2vector if (isinstance(x, str) and (x == ds_class)) else x)`

Answer (score 1):

choose **eval** buildin function is easy to use and easy to read.

```
# First ensure use object store str
df['col2'] = self.df['col2'].astype(object)
# read
arr_obj = eval(df.at[df[df.col_1=='xyz'].index[0], 'col2']))
# write
df.at[df[df.col_1=='xyz'].index[0], 'col2'] = str(arr_obj)
```

real store display perfect human readable value:

```
col_1,  col_2
xyz,    "['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']"
```

Comment: Using eval() is usually not a good idea. Transforming freely between strings and code is insecure and confuses the IDE/linter/type-checker/other people reading your code. Consider using the other methods mentioned in this post.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap what you want to store in a cell to a `list` object through first `apply`, and extract it by `index 0`of that `list` through second `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'a': ['on', 'on', 'off', 'off'],
                   'b': ['on', 'off', 'on', 'off']})


df['new'] = df.apply(lambda x: [np.array(x)], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x[0])

df
```

output:

```
    id  a       b       new
0   1   on      on      [1, on, on]
1   2   on      off     [2, on, off]
2   3   off     on      [3, off, on]
3   4   off     off     [4, off, off]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my 2 cents contribution (tested on Python 3.7):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataArray = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0])
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['User Col A'] = [1]
df['Array'] = [dataArray]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want some of the columns you could do something lie this. Taking the example of @allenyllee,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'a': ['on', 'on', 'off', 'off'],
                   'b': ['on', 'off', 'on', 'off']})

df['new'] = df[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: np.array(x), axis=1)
```

which outputs

```
   id    a    b         new
0   1   on   on    [on, on]
1   2   on  off   [on, off]
2   3  off   on   [off, on]
3   4  off  off  [off, off]
```

you can also change the order of [['a', 'b']] if you need a specific order.