# Assign a numpy array to a specific cell of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, numpy

Is it possible to store a numpy array in a single pandas cell? For example, let's assume we have the following df

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df= pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns =["A","B","C"], index =np.arange(5))
```

It is possible to set a specific cell as follows

```
df.ix[1,"A"]=2 # This works
```

However, if I try to assign an numpy array, it fails with a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` exception.

```
df.ix[1,"A"]=np.arange(5) #This fails
```

Is there any way to solve this? There is a similar [solution on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45548507/8943544) and it suggests to pass the values as numpy array as list but it seems not to work in my case.

```
df.ix[1,"A"]=list(np.arange(5)) #This also fails
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ix`, it's deprecated, use either `iloc` or `loc`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your df to `object` then using `at`

```
df=df.astype(object)
df.at[2, 'A']=np.arange(5).tolist()
df
Out[422]: 
                 A    B    C
0              NaN  NaN  NaN
1              NaN  NaN  NaN
2  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]  NaN  NaN
3              NaN  NaN  NaN
4              NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know how to convert the df back to a numeric datatype?  the `df.apply(pd.to_numeric)` the approach does not work in my case since the cell is saved as a string of values like this`"[792.6825 792.625  792.44   ... 896.795  897.1425 897.59  ]"`

Comment: @LiamdeBoeuf look at `ast`