# Data frame with varying third dimension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two numpy arrays with the following dimensions

Array1

```
(3,6)
```

Array2

```
(3,5)
```

Can I concatenate this into a pandas df with dimensions `(2,3, )` i.e third dimensional being varied?
So, if I query the first row of the resulting DF, I get a numpy array of dimension `(3,6)` and if I query the second row of the resulting DF, I get a numpy array of dimensions `(3,5)`

In both cases the one of the dimensions of the input array is constant.

Thanks!

Comment: This is simply a matter of storing the NumPy array into the data frame's only column.  Where are you having trouble?

Comment: I have created a DF and trying an append to it ````DF.append(Array1)```` but it gives me ````cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid````

Comment: Convert it to a series, then?

Comment: Converting it to a series seems to not preserve the dimensions...so the behaviour of pandas is a bit confusing here...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548426/store-numpy-array-in-cells-of-a-pandas-dataframe - this link helped me sort out my confusion. Thanks!